# window.innerHeight incorrect even in ngAfterViewInit

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm having trouble getting my `window.innerHeight` to correctly be determined, in Angular 4. I need to know the height, because I have two rows, and together both will fill the screen, the first row is always 140px OR 30px, while the second needs to "fill the rest".

I could do `calc(100vh - 140)` in the CSS, but since it's height changes to 30px, I can't do it with CSS alone.

Therefore, I need to solve this in JS/TS too.

The problem is that the `window.innerHeight == 720` upon launch, if I type it into the console after launch, it's correct, so it's clearly a lifecycle issue.

And indeed I can solve the issue with:

```
//Put this task on the end of the queue, so we can get the correct height.
setTimeout(() => { //So hacky, i hate it!
    this.resizeEmail();
}, 0)
```

However, I don't like this "solution" at all.

Does anyone know how to get the correct height, without using `setTimeout`?

I've tried putting the code in `ngOnInit` , `ngAfterViewInit` and `ngAfterContentInit`.

Thanks.

Comment: _“I could do calc(100vh - 140) in the CSS, but since it's height changes to 30px, I can't do it with CSS alone”_ - based on what does the height of this first row change, what triggers it?

Comment: can you setup a simple plunker?

Comment: Seems you have some asynchronous logic which will change details of `first row`, you may subscribe to those asynchronous logic and do resize there.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [NgZone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone)

An injectable service for executing work inside or outside of the Angular zone.

The most common use of this service is to optimize performance when starting a work consisting of one or more asynchronous tasks that don't require UI updates or error handling to be handled by Angular. Such tasks can be kicked off via [runOutsideAngular](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#runOutsideAngular) and if needed, these tasks can reenter the Angular zone via [run](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#run).

And use **ngAfterViewInit** for any initialization that needs the view be rendered like `jQuery plugin` or `simple external DOM manipulations`, this will avoid you use `setTimeout` in most of the other hooks.

```
    import {Component, NgZone} from '@angular/core';

    export class NgZoneDemo {

      constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone) {}

      ngAfterViewInit(){
             this._ngZone.run(() => { this.resizeEmail(); });
      }    

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    //insert logic with height or width calulations here.
}, 200);
```

This works 80% of the time .orientation change needs a delay to pick up on the new heights and widths.